# How to connect between the form "firstname" to my function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JS and I practice, I want to connect between my form "firstname" to my function so when someone will click the button it will change the headline to "Hello ____ (his name)". I can't understand what should I add and where to my code so it will work. Thanks for your help.

```
 <h1 class="example"> My Application </h1>

       <body>
       <form action="/action_page.php">
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" >
        <br>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form> 

      <button onclick="Hello(name)">Click here to change headline</button>

`<script>`
function hello(name){
    return document.querySelector(".example").innerHTML = "Hello" + name ;
}     

</script>
```

Comment: `name` in the function call is the name of `window`, remove the argument, and get the value of the input using `document.querySelector('[name="firstname"])` in the handler function. Also, there's no need for the `return` statement in the click handler, the return value is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few small issues in your code, but you were close. You're not passing anything into the function, you just have to get the values from your form. There are several ways to do this, but without overly complicating what you already have or understand, here's a working version.

```
  <h1 class="example"> My Application </h1>
   <form action="/action_page.php">
      First name:<br>
      <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstname" value="" >
      <br>
      Last name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form> 

  <button onclick="Hello()">Click here to change headline</button>

<script>
   function Hello(){
      var name = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
      document.querySelector(".example").innerHTML = "Hello " + name ;
   }     
</script>
```

Notice the addition of the 'id="firstName"' attribute to your input.